# Relationship of a model with an array of Ids of other model in Lucid Mongo

Tags: mongodb, adonis.js

Right now, I have a mongoldb database of a classroom and make an API using AdonisJS & Lucid Mongo. In the classroom there's a collection called `students` and another called `classes`. The structure of both collections are the following.

```
students = {
   _id: ObjectID
   name: string
   age: number
}

classes = {
   _id: ObjectID
   name: string
   professorId: ObjectID
   students: ObjectID[]
}
```

As you can see, in `classes` collection I have an array with students. How can I call this relationship using Lucid Mongo or just simple **mongodb**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Lucid Mongo doesn't support yer aggregate pipeline but I solve this using `referMany` method in `Classes` model as follow:

```js
 students() {
     return this.referMany('App/Models/Student','_id','studentsId)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

well if you are early in your schema design you should flatten out of a related table design into a single collection where class is a doc in the student collection:

```js
 students = {
   _id: ObjectID
   name: string
   age: number
   class = {
   _id: ObjectID
   name: string
   professorId: ObjectID
}}
```

In the related schema that you have now; one must use an aggregate pipeline on the class collection and $unwind the Class - Student array into individual student docs by student and then $lookup the Student collection.

Comment: Sure this could work if a student only takes one class but it’s not the case. A student can take as many classes he wants. With this approach what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

well if the original question is how to 'call the relationship' and you have those 2 collections - the method is to use $lookup on the related field (name).

where you go from there depends on the specifics of what data/fields you wish to display in your final query results.

that a student is in multiple classes doesn't change the $lookup need.  It will impact how your final query is designed and that depends on the specific results you seek i.e. single student, all students, class count, class names, etc...

if you are early in your schema design and can change from related to flat - as per my first post - this is more efficient in an NoSQL approach. for instance a simple $match on a student would make the display of their classes very simple.  It can also be done in the related collections you now have but it is a little more involved.